# How to change the loop?

Tags: autohotkey

The script is searching for a certain text in the clipboard. When found, it shows a MsgBox.

I would like this script to stop when the text has been found. How to achieve that?

```
#Persistent

MouseMove, 821, 700
Sleep, 500
MouseClick, Left
Sleep, 500
Loop, 5
{
Send, ^c
Sleep, 500
Send, {PgDn}
}

OnClipboardChange:

 If InStr( Clipboard, "Part3" )

    SetTimer, PopupMsgBox, -1

Return



PopupMsgBox:

 Msgbox, Part3 Found

Return
```

Comment: _I would this script pauses or stops every time when the MsgBox appears_  this sentence is not quite clear, please clarify what you are trying to achieve. While a `Msgbox` is displayed the script is not processing any more commands, so it is already paused until you press a button or close the `Msgbox`.

Answer (score 0):

```
#Persistent

clip_search := "Part3"

MouseMove, 821, 700
Sleep, 500
MouseClick, Left
Sleep, 500
Loop, 5
{
  Send, ^c
  ClipWait
  If InStr( Clipboard, clip_search )
  {
    MsgBox, % clip_search " Found."
    Break
  }
  Sleep, 500
  Send, {PgDn}
}
```

Comment: Thanks, works great, but not always detect the expected message and still running instead of breaking. I am using this at Remote Desktop, any ideas how to improve that simple code? I was thinking about activating the window on remote by script instead of mouse moving with coordinates but I am not experienced with this language.

Comment: Well, it deppends on what kind of thing you're trying to automate.

Comment: This is a simple window, similar to DOS, just lines of messages and black background.. Without script, only need to do is left mouse click on that window(no matter where, just to make it active) and then press PgDn button to scroll and search a certain message.